# Remove some rewrite rules in wordpress

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

It seems that the `add_rewrite_rule` works only if the `permalink` is set to non empty value in wp-admin/setting page. Isn't it?

Then once I set that value to `/item/%post_id%`, I got the rewrite rules like this through debugging:https://i.stack.imgur.com/G05pK.jpg.

There are too many rules not necessary in my case, is it possible to remove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the global [`WP_Rewrite`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) variable directly.

```
add_action('init', function(){

    global $wp_rewrite;

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($wp_rewrite);
    wp_die();
});
```

There are sevel properties you can adjust:

- $wp_rewrite->permalink_structure
- $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes
- $wp_rewrite->author_base
- $wp_rewrite->search_base
- $wp_rewrite->comments_base
- $wp_rewrite->pagination_base
- $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base
- $wp_rewrite->feed_base
- $wp_rewrite->front
- $wp_rewrite->root
- $wp_rewrite->index
- $wp_rewrite->matches
- $wp_rewrite->rules
- $wp_rewrite->extra_rules
- $wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top
- $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules
- $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs
- $wp_rewrite->endpoints
- $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_rules
- $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules
- $wp_rewrite->rewritecode
- $wp_rewrite->rewritereplace
- $wp_rewrite->queryreplace
- $wp_rewrite->feeds

And alternate removal functions:

- $wp_rewrite->[remove_permastruct](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_permastruct/)
- $wp_rewrite->[remove_rewrite_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_rewrite_tag/)